# Keeping multiple consoles from disappearing when their processes complete

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm building a C++ project in Xcode 4.3.2. While editing in Xcode, I would like to run multiple instances of the program with different parameters at the same time. I cout<< my output, which is the most important part of my program right now, to the console (the Xcode console, not the terminal) and I can keep tabs on all my processes while they're running when I am sitting at my computer by selecting the drop-down menu with the different process numbers right above the console. But if I set 3 processes to run and then leave my computer, when the processes are done only the console of the last program to finish remains.

Does anyone know of an Xcode Preferences setting where I can get all the consoles to stay open when they complete? Short of that, any other suggestions for keeping my console output? I would like to avoid writing my output to a log file, or at least having to hard code that in.

Comment: This might not be the most efficient way but just build all 3 versions (modifying the name of the excutable each time) and then just do in the commandline "whatever.exe > output.txt"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you start your application through Finder.
What if you open a terminal window with different tabs and simply run different instances of your program separately in each tab ?

Or another solution would be putting "std::cin>>" at the end of your main functions, thus forcing your app to wait for keyboard entry.

Comment: I would think there ought to be some setting in Xcode that will keep the consoles from disappearing when finished and so I'll wait to accept this answer in case somebody knows how, but std::cin>> is easy and I think will work. Thank you.

To clarify, I am editing and testing my program in the Xcode IDE, not through Terminal.